# 自分のインターネットの閲覧履歴を取得したいのですが、いい方法はないでしょうか？

Tags: firefox, google-api, browser

自分のインターネットの閲覧履歴を自然言語解析にかけてみたいのですが、そもそもプログラムが扱えるような形で閲覧履歴を取得するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

GoogleのAPIにそれらしいものはなかったので、ブラウザに拡張機能を仕込むなり、自分のPC内でブラウザの閲覧履歴を定期的に取得するなりするしか方法はないかな...と考えているのですが、あまり良案ではない気もします。
ご助言等いただけると助かります。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/110933

Comment: ご指摘の通りです。色んなアイデアをいただければと思ったのですが、マナーが悪かったかもしれないと思っています。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

私の場合は、こんな感じでFirefoxの最近の履歴URLを取得しています（Linuxの場合）。

```
$ sqlite3 ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/places.sqlite 'SELECT p.url FROM moz_historyvisits AS h INNER JOIN moz_places AS p ON h.place_id = p.id ORDER BY h.id DESC LIMIT 100'
```

いろいろな言語でSQLiteのクライアントライブラリがあるので、コード中で同様のSQL文を発行すれば、それを元に処理できると思います。